# Where is Jupyter notebook data saved?

Tags: jupyter

Where is Jupyter notebook data saved? 
Is data made viewable to the public when you install Jupyter notebook, how does the token work? Where does the notebook go when you uninstall Anaconda?

Comment: I mostly use `ipython`, rather than notebooks.  But when I start a `jupyter notebook` session I get page with `files` listing - for the directory where I started the server.  I also get that directory in a `notebook` with the `%pwd` magic (and `%ls`).  There may be more setup options, but that's the default.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is saved locally on your PC, it is not shared to public nor removed upon uninstalling anconda from your PC.
simply you can locate your code by typing in you jupyter notebook `pwd` which stands for **print working directroy**.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Jupyter handbook - Common Directories and File Locations](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-directories.html) the **data**:

> Jupyter uses a search path to find installable data files, such as
>   kernelspecs and notebook extensions. When searching for a resource,
>   the code will search the search path starting at the first directory
>   until it finds where the resource is contained.
>
> Each category of file is in a subdirectory of each directory of the
>   search path. For example, kernel specs are in kernels subdirectories.

I think you are also interested in the **Runtime files**:

> Things like connection files, which are only useful for the lifetime
>   of a particular process, have a runtime directory.
>
> On Linux and other free desktop platforms, these runtime files are
>   stored in $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/jupyter by default. On other platforms,
>   it’s a runtime/ subdirectory of the user’s data directory (second row
>   of the table above).
>
> An environment variable may also be used to set the runtime directory.

Comment: So does that mean it is only saved on my PC and not another server elsewhere?

Comment: I have not used Jupyter myself but that would be my understanding of it yes

Comment: Thanks Fuzzybear, but i thought the jupyter files were shared with other users?